# Delay function to postpone IObservable values dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, delegates, system.reactive

[ *This question is regarding [IObservable / Rx](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2010/02/19/rx-reactive-extension-for-beginner-part-1.aspx)* ]

#### Working Fixed Delay

```
var frequency = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
Result.Delay(frequency).Subscribe(i => Debug.WriteLine("After Fixed Delay"));
```

#### Pseudo-Code for Variable Delay

```
Result.Delay(GetAsymptotingTime()).Subscribe(i => Debug.WriteLine("After Changing Delay"));
```

While the code for variable delay compiles it gets called only once, providing only the first value (essentially a fixed value).

- How could you subscribe with a dynamic delay in Reactive Extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works:

```
source
  .SelectMany(i => Observable.Timer(GetAsymptotingTime()).Select(_=>i))
```

If your delays are decreasing, the resulting stream may be in a different order to the original stream.

Comment: Based on my initial testing your code works perfectly (with an increasing time function)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there is a new overload of .Delay that allows this functionality within RX itself:

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/03/12/reactive-extensions-v2-0-beta-available-now.aspx :

```
var res = input.Delay(x => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x.Length)));
```

Given the user input, it gets delays for a duration equal to the length of the input in seconds. Stated otherwise, the delay of each element can now be dependent on the data itself.

Comment: This should be accepted as answer since the code is clear and it is the Rx way to achieve dynamic delays.

Comment: Are you sure the Delay overload is used correctly in your sample?

Answer (score 2):

May be I did not get the question right, 
but I've steped into it when I was searching a way
to put same fixed delay between items, that are coming too fast. The previsous solution did not work for me, (RX 4.0) actionally the was no delay at all.

My solution is simple:

```
myObservable.Zip(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)), (a, _) => a)
```

I've used it when testing dynamic sequence like

```
      using var d2 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 }
        .ToObservable()
        .Zip(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)), (a, _) => a)
        .Do(a => Log.Logger.Debug("b {a}", a))
        .Subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delay once then you can use Observable.Delay.  I don't know what the type of Result is, so I'll assume it's an IObservable already, so, you can do something like:

```
    var Result = Observable.Range(0, 10);
var frequency = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500);
var delay = Result.Delay(frequency);
delay.Subscribe(x => Debug.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: your code achieves a fixed delay, which is exactly what i have got working already (my first code sample, where Result is indeed an IObservable) - but this question is not about delaying by a fixed amount of time, but the delay should be a function with a variable return value (`GetAsymptotingTime()`; which should be called multiple times on each value of the IObservable)