# How to create infinite Observable sequence that emits items at random intervals?

Tags: c#, .net, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I want to create an Observable that emits items at random intervals.

I've found an answer, but it refers to Rx.Js, that I don't know how to translate to Rx.NET

[How to create an infinite Observable that produces random numbers at random intervals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41388199/how-to-create-an-infinite-observable-that-produces-random-numbers-at-random-inte)

How can I do it in .NET?

Comment: I think this was closed incorrectly. I'm not looking to delay the items of an **existing** observable, but to **create** one *infinite* observable that emits items at random delays. The answers provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071004/delay-function-to-postpone-iobservable-values-dynamically solve a different scenario.

Comment: For those interested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733906/generate-numbers-at-random-time-intervals-with-rx is probably closer to the answer wanted and should be what it should be marked as Duplicate with.

Comment: @GlennWatson Exactly. I've tried that. You've also noticed for sure that that answer doesn't apply either, because generating an infinite sequence with that approach hangs the computer :)

Comment: @SuperJMN `Observable.Generate` from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30736875/958732) to the question linked by Glenn Watson does exactly what you want. `var random = new Random();
var infiniteRandomDelaySequence = Observable.Generate(
 initialState: 0,
 condition: x => true,
 iterate: x => random.Next(0, 100),
 resultSelector: x => x,
 timeSelector: x => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(random.Next(0, 1000))
 ).TimeInterval().Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", x.Value, x.Interval))` If it hangs your program something else is wrong.

Comment: I think your thread being blocked issue is due to `Observable.Generate` being run on the Immediate scheduler. `Generate` has a parameter that takes an `IScheduler` which you can specify a scheduler that executes on a separate thread. I think the rest of that other question/answer solves your issue.

Comment: @GlennWatson Exactly! that was the issue! Thanks for helping again!